# Create a Map<Integer, Set<String>> from a Stream<String>

Tags: java, maps, java-stream

Hey Guys I need to create a `Map<Integer, Set<String>>` from a `Stream<String>`
I just started learning Streams so I stuck a little bit.

The task is to create a Map to group Strings with the same length.

I dont get how to put the String from the Stream into the Map Set.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: have you tried `groupBy()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group your stream of `String` by string length and then use `Collectors.toSet()` to collect them into a `Set`

```
Map<Integer, Set<String>>  map = 
        stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length, Collectors.toSet()));
```

Comment: Oh wow.. Thank you. :)
Was playing around with so many stream operations..

Comment: You're welcome~